# PHP session page protect not functioning as thought

Tags: php, session, authentication

This is the login PHP code

```
<?php
session_start();

if( isset($_SESSION['user_id']) ){
header("Location: index.php");
}

require 'database.php';

if(!empty($_POST['username']) && !empty($_POST['password'])):

$records = $conn->prepare('SELECT id,user,password FROM users WHERE user = :user'); 
$records->bindParam(':user', $_POST['username']);
$records->execute();
 $results = $records->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

  $message = '';

 if(count($results) > 0 && md5($_POST['password'],     $results['password'])     ){

    $_SESSION['user_id'] = $results['id'];
    header("Location: index.php");

    } else {
        $message = 'Sorry, something went wrong';
    }
?>
```

This is what is supposed to protect my page

```
<?php
session_start();

if(!isset($_SESSION['user_id']) || $_SESSION['user_id']!=1){
header('Location: login.php');
}
?>
```

Even when I am logged in it redirects me to my login.php.
What am I missing?

Comment: Is your `user_id` equal to `1`? Also, don't use MD5 to save passwords, please...

Comment: changed it to sha1 :)

Comment: Please use PHP's [built-in functions to handle passwords](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.password.php) ([tutorial](http://jayblanchard.net/proper_password_hashing_with_PHP.html)). If you're using a PHP version less than 5.5 you can use the password_hash() [compatibility pack](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat).

Comment: echo $_SESSION['user_id'] and see what it has

Comment: @MoussaKhalil I just did it but a got a blank page return with this "
session_start();
 echo $_SESSION['user_id']{
  
}
''

Comment: Try echoing $results['id'] after the query

Maybe the id you want is not being pulled

Comment: @MoussaKhalil Still a blank page :(

Comment: Echo everything, $_POST variables and  $message in the end. I don't think you are finding the record you want

Comment: @MoussaKhalil I did, and all were either blank page or already set variables?